# How to Install libGDX Without Android SDK

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm wondering if it's possible to install libGDX without the android SDK. I don't want to have it create a bunch of projects for HTML, Android, and IOS I just want a Desktop app. Is this possible? If not, is there any other openGl library like libGDX? I'm wondering because Slick2D stopped being developed and libGDX is all that I know that's left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to run only the Desktop version, you can download the setup program and run it you will have to uncheck the boxes for Android, iOS and HTML, so you are left only with Desktop.

[Download set up program here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html)

Comment: Thank you. I was following a tutorial that must have been outdated. It didn't have the check-boxes. It should work now. :)